# Does Spring Data Couchbase support Inheritance

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

Clicking around the documentation for Spring Data Couchbase I can't find any suggestion that @Document's can extend other @Documents?  Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?
For example:

```
@Document
class A {...}

@Document 
class B extends A {...}
```

Comment: it should work but you be careful about the Id annotation defining the key. It can be on only one Class.